# AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'readlines'

Tags: python, python-3.x, paramiko

I connect with paramiko on a cisco device. I know I can use netmiko instead of paramiko but this is not the focus of my question at the moment. Nevermind, until I excuted the command "show run | i hostname\n" and save the output to the variable "hostOutput", I want to search in lines for the word "hostname". When the word is found, I want to get the complete line printed.

```
def devInfo(): 
print ('')
print ('[3] Collecting device informations...')
print ('')
ssh.slave.send('show run | i hostname\n')
time.sleep(1)
hostOutput = ssh.slave.recv(9999).decode('UTF-8')
lines = hostOutput.readlines()
for line in lines:
   if re.search(r'hostname', line):
     print line
     break
devInfo()
```

But I get the exception AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'readlines'... What did I wrong? How I can fix the unicode, make it to a str?

Comment: Maybe Iam a little bit confused now but I can not find the problem in my example without an file to open...

Comment: hostOutput is already a string. Use `lines = hostOutput.split('\n')` instead.

Comment: Just to put this into perspective for you, the file's `readlines()` function is of questionable design, because a free function taking a file or a string would have been better. Having it as memberfunction then begets the question why a string class like `unicode` (which can also be split into lines) does not have one. BTW: As a new user here, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Also, for problems with actual code, always extract and provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Simply type cast `hostOutput = ssh.slave.recv(9999).decode('UTF-8')` to **str** as follows :

```
hostOutput = str(hostOutput)
lines = hostOutput
```

or

```
lines = str(hostOutput).readlines()
```